# Queued responses from SQL server with ASP website hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5, delay

We're running an ASP website in IIS 7.5.
The site has a SQL backend database, running on a seperate SQL server.
There is a 10Gb fiber connection between both of these servers via a switch.

We're seeing some delays in requests to the SQL server being answered.. so like a request to add a record might go through within 0.25 seconds for one user, but then the same task might take 6 seconds for another user, or even the same user but later on in the day.

I haven't as of yet been able to identify any pattern to the performance issues, except to say it seems as if something is getting queued somewhere.

The machines themselves are virtual machines hosted on HyperV hypervisors.
They have an absolute abundence or memory and CPU resource allocated to them.
The network on the hypervisors is bonded for redundancy, and VMQ is disabled.

I've had perfmon running on both servers for quite a while and can't see anything obvious that points me in a particular direction.

Has anyone seen this sort of behavour before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. This question is about infrastructure and requires an IT expert to analyze it.

Comment: how did you identify that requests to SQL are getting queued? 
Few checks you can do:
What is the TPS to your Web or appServer when do you see this behavior?
Check your IIS settings to see the threads per process and CPU allowed
Identify which queries are taking longer
Check if you are initiating transactions from app server code

Comment: I haven't identified it as such; It just seems that way because of how it performs. It feels like we're hitting the ceiling on some throughput limit somewhere and so requests are being queued. Could be wrong with that though of course...